# Find highest resolution youtube video thumbnail from array of image tags

Tags: javascript, youtube

I am able to retreive youtube image thumbnail info [using something like this codepen](https://codepen.io/beardofprey/pen/MXmxXR?editors=1010) but what i need to do is figure out, of the 4 or 5 thumbnail resolutions, which is the highest. Traditionally, there is /mddefault, /maxresdefault, /sddefault, etc.. What i want to do is try to see if /maxresdefault.jpg exists, if not see if /hqdefault.jpg exists, etc. I have tried [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api), [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18029550/fetch-youtube-highest-thumbnail-resolution), [this link](https://www.thewebtaylor.com/articles/how-to-get-a-youtube-videos-thumbnail-image-in-high-quality) as well as some other methods, but can't find an efficient way to see if the image exists... I also tried using jQuerys `$.get(img_url)`, but interestingly, even if the image exists, it comes back as false... What can I do to logically determine what the highest res thubnail is in JS?

I also tried to use a regex like `let regex = /\b(?:maxres|hq|sd|mq)\b/gi;` and iterate through to see what the highest res image that existed was. But could not confirm if the image did in fact exist.

Does anyone know the best method for this?

```
  for (var i = 0; i < ytplayer.length; i++) {
    // step 1 - check if there is maxresdefault.jpg 
    // step 1a - if true, save the data to the variable
        var source = "https://img.youtube.com/vi/"+ ytplayer[i].dataset.embed +"/maxresdefault.jpg"; <===== try to get /maxresdefault.jpg
   //step 2 - if false (how do we know), see if there is /hddefault.jpg, the sddefault.jpg, then mddefault.jpg
   // step 2a - save to variable
```

Answer (score 0):

Youtube sends an blank image with 120x90 size if the thumbnail doesn't exist with that resolution. so all you need to do is check the width and height of the `image`.

here's an example of empty thumbnail:

[image]

and here's the code you can use to check if the thumbnail is empty:

```
if(image.width === 120 & image.height === 90)
    //the thumbnail doesn't exist
```